# How to use Zend Framework Begining of time

Tags: zend-framework

first ive already installed zend framework skeleton application with command from and composer.phar`php composer.phar require zend.....` and i type `composer suggests` and then install all the suggested application on my computer.

```
composer require zend...
```

know i have many file and folder about zend framework, but i cant use it.
can anybody tell me about how to use or implement zend framework.
in the code i understand a litle but its blanks on the `Controller` and `Bootstraps`.
for know i want to know about to use zend framework, thanks.

Comment: If you trying to learn ZF1 here is a link of my blog which might help you: https://zendframework1tutorial.wordpress.com

Comment: ok i learn the ZF2, is there have big diferent?

Comment: Yeah it's have big difference.

Comment: i visit the blog, i have more information now, 
but i will learn zf2, its possible to leard zf2 without zf1?

Comment: Yeah It's possible you can directly learn zf2. If you are new to PHP MVC frameworks than I suggest you to start with `codeigniter` or `laravel` type of small framework. because zf2 has stiff learning curve.

Comment: i'am done download laravel and ci i will try it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to teach you how to use ZF in a single answer would cost **a lot**, because of the complexity of the framework. Since that, I strongly recommend you to read the tutorial that Zend guys prepared for us to learn the use of the framework.

If you are using ZF1: [Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html)

If you are using ZF2: [Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html)

I really think it's a good starting point and, if in the future you have more specific questions, you can (obviously) ask them here.

I hope this helps and welcome you to Zend Framework ;).

Comment: yeah ive already read it, but its to far. can you link some page that give me step by step tutorial.

Comment: I really think about those as step by step tutorials to learn Zend, this one is where I go whenever I want to search something, anyway: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/index.html

Comment: thank you, and if you have some blog about tutorial don't forget to give me the links.